# Conflicto DELETE Statement con referencia a Foreign Key

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Uso SQL Server 2017 con Management Studio y Java 8.

Tengo una base de datos sobre películas y recibo error al intentar borrar una película que está haciendo referencia a otra tabla que actúa como intermedia.

Diagrama (valores de ejemplo en color rojo):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error:

> SQLServerException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE
>   constraint "FK_PELICULAS_GENEROS_PELICULAS". The conflicted occurred
>   in database "industriaCine", table "dbo.PELICULAS_GENEROS", column
>   "id_pelicula".

Código para eliminar:

```
public boolean eliminarPelicula(int id) {
        sSQL =  "DELETE FROM peliculas WHERE id_pelicula=?";

        boolean resultado;

        // Java 7 try-with-resources
        try (PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement(sSQL)) {

            pstm.setInt(1, id);
            pstm.executeUpdate();

            resultado = true;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SQLException:\n" + e, "Error: eliminarPelicula()", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            resultado = false;
            }

        return resultado;
    }
```

La Foreign Key la hice de esta manera:

```
ALTER TABLE PELICULAS_GENEROS ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PELICULAS_GENEROS_PELICULAS FOREIGN KEY (id_pelicula) REFERENCES PELICULAS(id_pelicula);
```

La idea es que si borro un `id_pelicula`, también se borre `id_pelicula` de la tabla `PELICULAS_GENEROS`. Ejemplo (como en la foto de arriba), si borro la película con `id_pelicula = 2`, el error aparece.

Primera vez que hago algo como esto.

Qué está pasando?, por qué el error?. Debo cambiar algo en SQL Management Studio en las referencias?.

Estoy perdido, gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error ocurre porque hay una referencia a un registro (en este caso, la película de id 2) en otra tabla, y quieres eliminar ese registro.
Por defecto, la base de datos no te dejará eliminarlo. Sin embargo, al crear la relacion, puedes especificarle mediante la query de ejecución que deseas que la base "elimine en cascada" al momento de eliminar un registro.
Lo mismo ocurre cuando deseas actualizar un registro.

```
ALTER TABLE peliculas_generos
drop CONSTRAINT [NOMBRE_CONSTRAINT de ID_PELICULA];

ALTER TABLE peliculas_generos
ADD CONSTRAINT [NOMBRE_CONSTRAINT de ID_PELICULA]
    FOREIGN KEY (id_pelicula)
    REFERENCES pelicua
        (id_pelicula)
    ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

*Aclaracion: Lo que está entre [ ] (con [ ] inclusive) es información a reemplazar.*

De todas formas, tu tienes control en java y puedes realizar fácilmente la eliminación en cascada de manera manual, es decir, primero eliminas de la tabla pelicula_genero cuando el id_pelicula sea = 2 y luego eliminas en la tabla pelicula. A veces con la simple creación de un método más puedes evitar errores a futuro.

Comment: Había intentado borrarlo desde la tabla PELICULAS_GENEROS, pero, no me dejó, me salía el mismo error. He cambiado esa relación a CASCADA y ahora funciona como deseaba. Gracias. Los `()` me confundieron al principio, pensé que iban incluídos en el query. jeje

Comment: disculpa por los (), ahora lo arreglo. De todas formas dejame decirte que puede llegar a ser una decisión peligrosa a futuro, depende la mutación de las tablas que tengas. Por ahí lo que estabas haciendo era elimianr primero de peliculas y despues de peliculas_generos, cuando lo que importa es el orden. Primero se elimina de las tablas referenciales (peliculas_generos) y luego, una vez que no quedan referencias, de la tabla principal (peliculas)

Comment: Lo estaba haciendo de esa manera, estaba eliminándolo de la tabla intermedia primero, pero, SQL me lanzaba el mismo error sobre referencias. Lo dejaré en CASCADA para este caso ya que era lo que necesitaba, de todas formas es un programa para práctica personal.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy muy familiarizado con SQLserver pero creo que el problema que tienes es que tratas de eliminar un registro de la tabla PELICULAS sabiendo que el id de PELICULA que está en la tabla PELICULAS_GENERO aún sigue persistiendo.

La solución sería eliminar primero los datos de la tabla PELICULA_GENERO:

```
DELETE FROM PELICULA_GENERO WHERE ID_PELICULA= 2
```

Luego propiamente eliminar el registro de la tabla PELICULA:

```
DELETE FROM PELICULA WHERE ID_PELICULA =2
```